# Connect to Quickbooks using QODBC driver remotely via PHP

Tags: php, odbc

I have Quickbooks installed on a local machine. QODBC is installed and I can successfully connect to QB both with their VB demo test tools and via PHP running on the local machine.

I'm simply using `odbc_connect("QuickBooks Data", "", "");`

However, I need to connect back to this machine from a remote machine where PHP is running the same script. What should the connection string look like? Should I be connecting to `QuickBooks Data` or `QuickBooks Data QRemote`

It seems that QRemote is meant to work only if the Remote Client is installed on the remote machine. As I'm connecting from a Linux (non gui) machine, I don't believe that's possible. However, I have opened up the necessary ports to connect to QRemote and verified via telnet that it's open.

How do I connect? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Windows machine instead of Linux machine, install PHP, use either IIS or Apache and install QODBC.

With QODBC , QRemote will get install automatically.  QRemote can work locally and remotely.

If you have QuickBooks Install the the PHP machine, you can use QuickBooks Data QRemote and connect locally.

Incase you have QuickBooks on remote machine, you can configure the DSN "QuickBooks Data QRemote" and  point to remote machine's IP Address.

QODBC driver is meant to be installed on a Windows machine to access the data.

Refer : 
Accessing QuickBooks Data Remotely using QODBC & QRemote. (Video)
http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2517/

How to use QODBC with PHP 
http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2623/0/how-to-use-qodbc-with-php

Answer (score 0):

For now, QODBC cannot be installed on Linux machine. But if you know any driver or method to link Linux to call DSN/Driver on the machine, you should be able to use QODBC from Linux.

Please share if you are interested in a Linux client for QRemote which will connect to QuickBooks Data on the Windows machine. We are collecting votes for Developing/Adding feature for Linux Client or QRemote Driver(Linux).  (To show you interest toward Linux client for QRemote, Raise a support ticket at http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Tickets/Submit )

For now, you can use a windows box at the remote site.

I would request you to refer
Accessing QuickBooks Data Remotely using QODBC & QRemote. (Video)

http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2517/

&

http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2483/0/using-quickbooks-data-remotely-via-qodbc

FAQ & Knowledge base : http://support.qodbc.com/